# Передать данные в компонент Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

У меня есть структура компонентов

```
<cb-result>
    <result-content>
        <cb-result__data></cb-result__data>
    </result-content>
    <next-button></next-button>
</cb-result>
```

Тело cb-result__data:

```
<p class="cb-result__data"> \
    <span>{{ title }}:</span> \
    <strong>{{ description }}</strong> \
</p>
```

Как мне из корневого экземпляра передать свойство в cb-result__data чтобы значение свойства отображалось в {{ description }}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью `props`:

[https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Передача-данных-через-входные-параметры](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)

```
<cb-result>
    <result-content>
        <cb-result__data testString="Hello, world!"></cb-result__data>
    </result-content>
    <next-button></next-button>
</cb-result>
```

И объявляете свойство в самом компоненте

```
props: ['testString']
```

Далее, вы можете взаимодействовать с свойствами, как с обычными данными компонента

```
<div> Родитель говорит: {{testString}} </div>
```

Также, следует почитать про `sync`
[https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Модификатор-sync](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-sync)

и глобальную шину данных

[https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Коммуникация-между-компонентами-не-связанными-иерархически](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Для более сложных приложений вы можете изучить vuex (только после освоения всех базовых вещей в библиотеке)

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html